# MySQL - Hostname Issue

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, mysql, centos, hostname

I'm experiencing an unusual issue with my production mysql server. Currently I only have two production servers so I had all the server host name entries in `/etc/hosts` files on each server. A few days ago I setup a DNS zone in hopes that I can remove the manual entries in the  `/etc/hosts` file.

Due to the fact I only have two production servers, I setup my DNS so that each server had a real hostname, which could be aliased too so that I can control connections by simply updating dns records. For example, server1 hosts httpd and mysql, so in my DNS zone I have server1 with an A record of 4.4.4.2 and store-ro with an alias to server1. Obviously 4.4.4.2 is not my real ip, demonstrative only.

After some configuration, I am able to connect to the local mysql instance via command line, but my application keeps throwing `Unknown MySQL server host 'store-ro'` errors. The only way I can fix the issue is if I add the following back to the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 store-ro
# or
4.4.4.2 store-ro
```

(Not sure if it matters, but my app is using Zend_Db to connect to the database.)

So the app can connect to the server if I enter loopback ip or the actual ip, but won't work if removed from the hosts file, so I thought maybe it was a DNS issue, but it appears that the server can resolve the hostname fine:

```
$ -> nslookup store-ro

Server:   72.14.179.5
Address:  72.14.179.5#53

Non-authoritative answer:
store-ro.example.com    canonical name = server1.example.com.
Name:   server1.example.com
Address: 4.2.2.2
```

I do have SELinux enabled, and a cursory glance over relevant httpd connection settings appear to be correct:

```
$ -> getsebool -a | ack httpd

httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
```

Plus there are no entries showing up in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

My hostname is set correctly:

```
$ -> hostname

server1
```

MySQL user perms:

```
mysql> select host, user from user;
+-----------+-------------+
| host      | user        |
+-----------+-------------+
| %         | ro_user_1   |
| %         | ro_user_2   |
```

And `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
search example.com
nameserver 72.14.179.5
nameserver 72.14.188.5
```

And `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

4.4.4.2 server1 server1.example.com # This shouldn't be necessary with DNS setup?
```

The only thing I can think of is if the alias to the cname may be causing the issue, but I doubt it. Any help is appreciated.

**--Update--**

Forgot to add the actual error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'store-ro'`

Per request here is the full row from the mysql table:

```
mysql> select * from user where user like '%core%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Host: %
User: ro_ml_core
Password: *2B5FEA45B69826783FD6F8601A9AFB1CFE916D52
Select_priv: N
Insert_priv: N
Update_priv: N
Delete_priv: N
Create_priv: N
Drop_priv: N
Reload_priv: N
Shutdown_priv: N
Process_priv: N
File_priv: N
Grant_priv: N
References_priv: N
Index_priv: N
Alter_priv: N
Show_db_priv: N
Super_priv: N
Create_tmp_table_priv: N
Lock_tables_priv: N
Execute_priv: N
Repl_slave_priv: N
Repl_client_priv: N
Create_view_priv: N
Show_view_priv: N
Create_routine_priv: N
Alter_routine_priv: N
Create_user_priv: N
Event_priv: N
Trigger_priv: N
Create_tablespace_priv: N
ssl_type:
ssl_cipher:
x509_issuer:
x509_subject:
max_questions: 0
max_updates: 0
max_connections: 0
max_user_connections: 0
plugin:
authentication_string: NULL
```

Comment: hey, can you paste complete output of `select host, user from user;`

Comment: @suku: Added the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to connect to the mysql server via the application. After implementing Suku's suggestion I restarted the mysql service, but still didn't work. So I figured I would restart the httpd service, and viola the app was able to connect again. It seems that if I remove the entry in /etc/hosts and don't restart the httpd service it has connection problems, but if I remove the entry and restart it works. Even adding back the entry to /etc/hosts didn't work until I restarted httpd.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select User,Host from user where user like '%core%';
+------------+-----------+
| User       | Host      |
+------------+-----------+
| ro_ml_core | %         |
| ro_ml_core | localhost |
+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> It is necessary to have both (`%` and `localhost`) accounts for `ro_ml_core` to be
>   able to connect from anywhere as `ro_ml_core`. Without the localhost account,
>   the anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by
>   `mysql_install_db` would take precedence when `ro_ml_core` connects from the
>   localhost. As a result, `ro_ml_core` would be treated as an anonymous user. The
>   reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific
>   Host column value than the `'ro_ml_core'@'%'` account and thus comes earlier in
>   the user table sort order.

About sort order:

> The server uses sorting rules that order rows with the most-specific
>   Host values first. Literal host names and IP addresses are the most
>   specific. (The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by
>   whether it has a netmask, so `192.168.1.13` and
>   `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0` are considered equally specific.) The pattern `'%'` means `"any host"` and is least specific. The empty string
>   `''` also means `"any host"` but sorts after `'%'`. Rows with the same Host
>   value are ordered with the most-specific User values first (a blank
>   User value means `"any user"` and is least specific).

Comment: Thanks for the information, I posted the answer to how I was finally able to resolve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in your resolv.conf you don't have

`search foo.com`

When mysql is doing a lookup for `store-ro`, `foo.com` is not appended to it. Another way of doing this is to use fqdn. Use `store-ro.foo.com` to connect.

Manpage snippet. `resolv.conf(5)`

> **search** 
>   Search list for host-name lookup.
>       The search list is normally determined from the local domain name; by default, it contains only the local domain name. This may be
>   changed by listing the desired domain search path following the search
>   keyword with spaces or tabs separating the names. Resolver queries
>   having fewer than ndots dots (default is 1) in them will be attempted
>   using each component of the search path in turn until a match is
>   found. For environments with multiple subdomains please read options
>   ndots:n below to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and unnecessary
>   traffic for the root-dns-servers. Note that this process may be slow
>   and will generate a lot of network traffic if the servers for the
>   listed domains are not local, and that queries will time out if no
>   server is available for one of the domains. 
>       The search list is currently limited to six domains with a total of 256 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I do have `search example.com` which is the domain to which `server1` belongs.